# How to Know Which Synonym to use From a Thesaurus.?

Tags: php, dictionary

When using a thesaurus, they typically offer multiple definitions per word and different synonyms for each definition. My question is, is there a way to automatically know which definition is the right one? I mean, of course, if I want to generate the correct definition automatically via software. I know you could use something like POS tagger software but this would't help if all definitions are part of the same POS.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: anyone have any idea?